# Is there a multilevel list bug in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a multilevel list I created.  I open the document containing it and opened a second document with the same style names but not the multilevel list 'settings'. I click on the Multilevel lists arrow and half the time I see ' lists in current documents'.

I click on my list from the other document and voila, new document has same multilevel list as the old. The other half of the time I click on the ML arrow and there is no 'lists in current document' section, and it randomly appears when I open various documents.

Answer (score 0):

I use format painter a lot.  Would that help you?  Copy from the document that is set the way you want it, and paint the format into the next document.  Beware, though, that the levels may get messed up.  Sometimes I have to join one paragraph to another (that has the proper multilist format) and then hit enter and to get the format in the next paragraph (enter and tab to get the next level down).

Answer (score 0):

You are far better off using the Define New MultiLevel List dialog as described in Word MVP Shauna Kelly's [Page on Outline Numbering](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

I summarized that in [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033).

The thing is, the gallery is temporary, confined to one computer. Much better is to set up a [Word Template](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm) with your numbering set up and use that as the basis for new documents.