# Importing numbered paragraph styles in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, numbering

I have a problem with importing numbered paragraph into any template.

In Template2020 file I have created four styles called Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4 with special indentations set
([Numbered paragraphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzFgZ.png)).

Now, I import them from the template.
Unfortunately, the settings of my styles have been changed and I do not understand why.
Here are the settings that are displayed in Organizer:

- [Number1 style settings in Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHNVY.png)
- [Number1 style settings in actual document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp0sl.png)

I have tried to use `copy` button three times but it gives no result!

Do you have any ideas why it happens like this. Why during copying the styles that concern numbered paragraphs styles are changed by MSWORD?

Comment: How did you export these four styles to Normal.dotm? I suggest you backup your previous Normal.dotm, then open the tempalte file, create the styles directly for a test.

Comment: @Emily, I am using WORD 2016 and I used standard `Import/Export` button in `Manage Styles` dialog. I will try to follow your hints.

Comment: The simplest way to get styles from a template into a document is to create a new document based on the template. This is true whether the styles are numbered or otherwise. The new document will have all of the styles from the template. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm. You can save that new document as a template if you want to make a template with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You should create a multi-level list following the directions found on MVP Shauna Kelly's page: [How to create Outline Numbering or Numbered Headings in Word](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

*Those instructions are for the latest Windows versions. Here is a [parallel page for the MAC versions](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/) by John Korchok. If you are using Word 97-2003 look for the link on Shauna Kelly's page for those versions.*

After you have the needed paragraph style for each level, Shauna Kelly's instructions start with the **Define New List Style** dialog rather than the *Define New MultiLevel List* dialog. For the most robust numbering this is needed. It takes you to defining the MulitLevel List as a step in the process. Many times you can skip directly to the Define New MultiLevel List dialog, but you should know that this occasionally fails.

Essentially, you need to link each level in such a list to an existing paragraph style. You apply the numbering in a document by applying the styles.

[image: define Multilevel list dialog]

You can do this directly by [opening the normal template](http://addbalance.com/word/normaltemplate.htm#Open) for editing, or using the [Style Organizer](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Organizer) to move the styles to that template. When using the Organizer, be sure to copy all of the related styles at the same time and copy them three times, overwriting existing styles. So you would want to be copying Number1, Number2, Number3, and Number4 at the same time and doing this three times.

[image: Organizer]

Ouoting [my page on the Organizer](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Organizer):

> I have found it best when copying styles using the organizer to copy
> them three times if any of the styles is based on other styles or is
> followed by other styles. I'm not sure why this makes a difference,
> but I've found that clicking on that copy button three times means
> that these relationships continue in the destination template. I know
> that when I copy them only once, they do not and the styles are then
> followed by the Normal style.

Here is a screenshot from a new document after copying the styles using the Organizer.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is a [temporary link to the document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ylamcw9mjwqa253/deleteme%20numbering.docx?dl=0) in which I added the numbering. It is very important to follow the procedures in [Shauna Kelly's page](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) when creating this.

1. Create unnumbered paragraph styles or use existing unnumbered paragraph styles.
2. Define new Multi-Level List.
3. Click on More Button
4. Give list a Name
5. Attach a separate paragraph style to each level

In setting up your indentation through the Define New Multi-Level List dialog you want to keep in mind how alignment of numbers work. Here is MVP Suzanne Barhill's page on [Number Alignment](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NumberAlignment2007.htm#NumberedLists).

Here is a good [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/niD6VXPvAyU?t=487) on setting up numbering with a List Style and MultiLevel List linked to styles. They may help clarify the instructions. I think it may be worthwhile to first read the instructions and then watch the video.

- [Saving custom paragraph numbering as List Styles](https://youtu.be/niD6VXPvAyU?t=487) by Deborah Savadra "Legal Guru"

**Styles in a multilevel list, when properly set up, can be a part of a [Quick] Style Set or transferred using a macro that uses the Organizer method.**

- [[Quick] Style Sets and Word Themes in Microsoft Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/quick-style-sets-and-word-themes-in-microsoft-word/444d4195-a28a-43bb-b035-facd84f7bd44)
- [[Quick] Style Sets](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#quick_style_set)
- [A Global Stylesheet for Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/word/stylesheet.htm#StartPage) - macro using organizer

Comment: I have tried the three `copy` button method but it does not work in my case. I have edited my question to show the differences in Organizer.

Comment: In my humble opinion it is a bug in MS WORD as all the other styles are copied normally.

Comment: As Far as the multi-level list issue unfortunately I am forced to do this with 4 separate paragraph styles.

Comment: **Yes, you need four separate paragraph styles but you attach them to one multi-level list.** *I've revised my answer with more details and a link to a sample document.* The problem is not with the Organizer but with how you created the numbering in your styles. The Organizer is used to copy the paragraph styles. That brings the list along. The Styles, with the numbering, copied very easily and show up in a new document generated from the Normal template.

Comment: I have been copying numbered styles in Word using the Organizer for more than 20 years. Here is my Add-In that does it with a macro. http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#GlobalStylesheet

Comment: (**Mac version**: [https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/][2] Archival link for Mac version: https://web.archive.org/web/20221102225202/https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/)