# Word: update sublist numbering automatically when the parent list changes

Tags: microsoft-word

I use Word 2019 on Windows machine. I already have created two lists like the following:

```
1   List item 1
2   List item 2
    2.1 Item
    2.2 Item 
    2.3 Item
3   List item 3
4   List item 4
```

Now I need to add a top level section above section 2. I copied the first section and pasted. It looks like this:

```
1   List item 1
2   List item 1
3   List item 2
    2.1 Item
    2.2 Item 
    2.3 Item
4   List item 3
5   List item 4
```

The number for the original section 2 becomes 3, but the sublist inside it still starts with "2". How can I make them automatically change to 3.1, 3.2, and 3.3 without me doing anything? I guess I need to connect the numbering of the nested list to the parent numbering somehow, but I don't know how to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to associate your numbering with styles through the Define New MultiLevel List Dialog.

See my answer at [Importing numbered paragraphs](https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033).

That relies on information from Word MVP Shauna Kelly on her page [How to create Outline Numbering or Numbered Headings in Word](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html)

Essentially, each level in numbering is associated with a separate existing paragraph style. Each associated style is associated with only one multilevel list level.

Comment: Thank YOU so much!!!