# Trouble with extra blank space on line when using "Chapter" Headings in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to format the chapter headings in my Microsoft Word like this:

"Chapter 1: "

Word seems to already have an option for this (highlighted in grey)
[image: Word Chapter Heading Option]

However, when I select this option as is, the chapter heading is slightly indented to the left compared to the rest of the text:

[image: Indented Heading]

I would like the chapter heading to be aligned to the left margin, like most of the paragraph is (except for the first line).

I can accomplish this if I change the tab level of the heading. However, if I do this, the chapter title text ("This Is Chapter One") remains to far to the left, with an unnecessary amount of space between the chapter number and the heading text:

[image: Hedaing title text too far left]

I would like there to be only one space between the colon and the chapter title, but I cannot figure out how to accomplish this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would love to see a sample of your file so I see what's wrong.

Comment: This is the dumbest thing in Microsoft Word ever. Spent hours on finding a solution, but there isn't one apparently for regular list/numbered titles. Then randomly after creating new .docx files and deleting them and creating new style for numbered chapter titles, the spaces disappeared. The solution exists, and it's probably some weird interaction with some bugs that was causing it in the first place that finally fixed my numbered heading titles from having random spaces after the number dependent on font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Define Multilevel List" tool, as suggested by Charles Kenyon, was half of the answer.

After opening that dialogue box, the key was to click "more" in the bottom left, and then change the  "Follow number with" option to "Nothing":

[image]

Comment: Did you read Shauna Kelly's article? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  Have you followed up on the etiquette of cross-posting?

Answer (score 0):

### There is no method to change the indent in the single-level list formats.

### You can and should use the Define MultiLevel List dialog following the steps in Word MVP Shauna Kelly's [page on numbering](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

That dialog allows changing of the Indent. You cannot change it in paragraph formatting nor in the List dialogs. Only through the Define MultiLevel List dialog can you change the indent. The process set in Shauna Kelly's page includes attaching each level to a separate existing paragraph style and using those styles to apply numbering (not the buttons on the ribbon).

Here is my page on [Numbering in Microsoft Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm).

This method was referenced in [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033).

Cross-posted in [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/trouble-with-extra-blank-space-on-line-when-using/a86d601b-0bd6-4ec3-8b87-b8d2ef5cf5ce) https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/trouble-with-extra-blank-space-on-line-when-using/a86d601b-0bd6-4ec3-8b87-b8d2ef5cf5ce and [Word Forum](https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/47926-trouble-extra-blank-space-line-when-using.html) https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/47926-trouble-extra-blank-space-line-when-using.html

For the etiquette for cross-posting please see [A Message for Cross-Posters](https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184). Please follow through with that etiquette.