# How do I insert/add text within a multilevel list for the body?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I am beyond frustrated with this issue, and cannot seem to find any resources online to help with this seemingly simple issue:

How do I insert or add text within a multilevel list?

I am trying to create documentation (SOP) for my office, and am trying to create a document with chapters and sections. I have seen a TON of videos and tutorials that demonstrate this, such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiChXfl2U8w

However, every single video or tutorial I see has the document already written, and involves highlighting the text you want and then clicking the corresponding header within the list. This is great and all, but how do I add NEW sections or chapters to my document, or even the text below it? For example, if I have two headers defined, Header 1 for Chapters, and Header 2 for Sections, I would want the following:

> Chapter 1 - Overview
> Text to briefly describe chapter.
>
> 1-1 Purpose
> Paragraph to describe the purpose.

How can I generate the Chapter 2 portion, or even add a section 1-2 and then put text beneath that? Normally, for list, I just hit enter and it creates the next list element. Just as well, how can I add text to go underneath the Chapter 2 portion?

Would really appreciate any guidance, or resources, on what I can do to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Switch to using a MultiLevel List attached to Styles and use Styles.

This method is explained step-by-step in [Word MVP Shauna Kelly's page on Numbering](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

I've outlined it in [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033).

Each numbered level in a list is attached or connected to a separate existing paragraph style. You assign the numbering level then by using styles. You use Body Text, Normal, or another non-outline level style for your text between numbered elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I had already came across the Word MVP link when searching for an answer before. I also reviewed your answer to another person's question.  Neither of these have the answer I am looking for. I already know how to create and use a multilevel list attached to styles. The video I posted shows exactly how to do that, and I have already followed along and done so.

Rather, it's that last part of your answer that I'm after. The using the text between numbered elements part. How exactly do I accomplish this?

Comment: For example, if I am working with Header 1 inside a MultiLevel list, how can I have some Body Text, Normal, or another non-outline text on the next line AFTER the Header 1 but BEFORE the Header 2 text?

If I hit enter after my Header 1 text, it just continues the Header 1 text on a new line. The same is true if I do shift + enter.

By the same token, what if I want to create a second Header 1 text on a new line, but that would be separate from the first Header 1 text (i.e. Chapter 1, Chapter 2)? What's the trick to do that? This is the stuff I can't seem to find an answer for online.

Comment: Apply the **STYLE**. Change the **STYLE**. Read my other post and  Shauna Kelly's page.

Comment: I thought I had it figured out for a moment; I could highlight, clicking on the heading, and then change the List Style to the one I was using. Then I dared to add just a regular numbered list within my current list style. Now I can't seem to get my document back to the flow it had before. I can add a line of text, click Heading 1, change the List STYLE to the one I created and it will update to the right Chapter. But if I add a section, it just seems to start right back at 1-1. What gives? If I'm on Chapter 3, it should be 3-3. It seems like adding that numbered list undid everything.

Comment: Until you are solid with this, once you have your numbering set up, totally ignore the numbering buttons on the home tab. Numbering should only be done by applying styles (as was shown in the video). It should be 3-1 not 3-3, and not 1-1. Only apply the styles. To get an unnumbered paragraph, you apply a different style to that paragraph.  Do not just "add a regular numbered list." Do not work with list styles. Work with paragraph styles.

Comment: For having unnumbered text, see this video:https://youtu.be/GevZOS-nCuw?t=539