# Microsoft Word won't restart numbered list (abc formatting)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

Using Microsoft Word 2016, I want to restart the highlight below instead of c to a.
Right clicking it, selecting "Set Numbering Value", "Set value to: a", nothing happens at all. It just remains c. 
Deleting the entire text (including the paragraph marker) and just starting fresh by entering some dummy text and then applying a numbered list, it will start at c. again also! 
Even though clearing the entire cell, there still appears to be some hidden formatting applying. Extremely frustrating, any help?

[image]

Why restart at c? It should be restart at a

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### This is best done with a multilevel list set up following [the procedures described by Word MVP Shauna Kelly](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

I outline these in [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033).

Basically, each level is attached to an existing paragraph style. These can be built-in styles or custom styles. This is done using the Define New MultiLevel List dialog.

Have your list set up so that the style used for "test" in your example is at a higher level than the a,b,c... level. The "test" level does not need to have any numbering.

You apply the numbering, once this is done, by using the styles.

The styles do not have to appear different *(i.e. can look the same)*.