# What is the point of Current List section in the Multilevel List dropdown

Tags: microsoft-word

The **Current List** section is shown even in the fresh new documents without any list.

[image: Current List]

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using these in the gallery and instead set up numbering following the method set forth by Word MVP Shauna Kelly in [her page on Outline Numbering](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

I summarized this in [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033).

### The point of your numbering scheme showing up in the gallery is to allow you to use a numbering scheme that you have set up in one document in a different one.

*This works but is not all that reliable.* It is only in the computer and you may not recognize it or be able to tell that it is the one you want after a few weeks or months. Much better is to have a template with the numbering tied to appropriate styles and use that as the basis for new documents.

Here is a link to [my page on Templates](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm) in Microsoft Word.

Comment: Your explanation is more applicable to the section Lists in Current Documents

Comment: What about the uppermost section Current List, which is never empty even in a blank document (with no other documents open).