# Restart at A breaks the Numbered List into two slots

Tags: microsoft-word

While trying to "Restart at A" to a Numbered List in MS-Word, unfortunately the restarted list breaks into two slots. A itself becomes one slot and the rest B to D becomes another slot. I can't figure out the problem. Please see the screenshot below before and after "Restart at A":

Continued List:

[image: Continued List]

Broken List - A:

[image: Broken List - A]

Broken List - B to D:

[image: Broken List - B to D]

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. Which version of Word/Office are you using? Can you post online (Dropbox, OneDrive etc) a small example document with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself. I am answering my own question so that if anyone faces this problem in future can get a solution easily. When you get a Continued Numbered List and want to Restart from beginnning (Here from A), please don't right click the Numbered List itself to restart the list. Instead select the List values and click the "Restart at A" from the context menu. It will not broken down your numbered list into two slot of list. See the attached pic:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: See my answer here for a more stable method of numbering: https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033