# Set a style for second and third level bullets in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have 'bullet-style' set in Word for first-level bullets.   I can manually adjust this using the first line indent and hanging indent sliders in the ruler then use right-click on this bullet-style in the styles part of the Home ribbon to get this style behaving just how I would like it to be.

However, I now want to have a second level (more indented bullet) below the first with a different bullet symbol and indent.  I can use the same manual method to get it looking how I would like but when I use the method described above to udpate the bullet style it changes the higher level bullet to this 'lower' level style. I cannot seem to find where you can set up a style that has all the bullet levels defined.  Any pointers on where there is a tutorial or example on how to set a style for bullet lists would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You should be using the Define New MultiLevel List Dialog rather than any of the Bullet buttons or dialogs

The key web resource on this is the late Word MVP Shauna Kelly's page [How to Control Bullets in Ribbon Versions of Word](http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html).

This is similar to the automatic numbering described in [my answer about numbering here](https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033) which is also based on one of her pages.

The Define New MultiLevel List dialog allows assigning bullet symbols instead of numbers. You can easily control the Indents for each level. Each level must be assigned to an existing paragraph style.

To use a bullet level, use the style, not the buttons on the Ribbon or keyboard shortcuts or AutoFormat. (You can assign a keyboard shortcut to each style if you want. Here is [my article on the Microsoft site on how to do this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330).)