# How to start new numbering system half way through word document

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

I am writing a word document that has several Parts/Sections, each Section's numbering needs to start at 1 using the Heading styles and not be a continuous flow of numbers from the previous section.  E.g: Section 1 has paragraphs numbered from 1 -9, I am now starting Section 2 and I want to also start the numbering of this section from 1, how do I do this using the Heading Styles that I already used in Section 1.

Comment: There's likely multiple ways to do so - I usually press `Enter` until it exits out of the lists format _(e.g. cursor is back to its normal paragraph alignment)_ → Create a new list → (1) Auto-correct icon should generate to the left of the new number - Click it and select _Restart Numbering_; or (2) Right-click on the number you want to restart numbering on → _Restart Numbering at 1_ OR _Set Numbering Value_ → _Start new list_ and _Set value to_: `1` _(I'll create an answer tomorrow, as I don't have the time at the moment)_

Comment: [How to create a list with restarting and continuing numbering - Microsoft Word 365](https://www.officetooltips.com/word_365/tips/how_to_create_a_list_with_restarting_and_continuing_numbering.html)

Comment: Each section of a document has its own page number configuration. Therefore, you have to set the numbering within each section of the document.

Comment: See my previous answer on setting up numbering in Word. https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033
---------------------------------------------------------

You want to be using a custom multilevel list tied to styles. One paragraph style for each level. A new level one paragraph can restart the numbering.