# numbered sub-bulletpoint with super-bulletpoint as prefix

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a bullet point situation that looks like this:

---

[image]

---

I want the sub-bulletpoint to be numbered like this:
`9.a.`

instead of `a.`

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you define new multiplelevel list.

The first level is like following image.

[image]

The second level, you can include the number from level 1, then set the number style and the text indent value.

[image]

Comment: I would refine this by attaching each level in the list to a distinct paragraph style. As in https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033.