# How to deal with advanced numbering in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am creating a document with quite advanced numbering:

```
1.1
  1.1.1
    1.1.1.1
      1.1.1.1.1
1.2
  1.2.1
  1.2.2
    1.2.2.1
```

Etc…

I am using the Define New Number Format for each of these new levels, and I find that when I set a new format the previous numbers of the same level change to the new format just created. I created a new format to start fresh from that moment, not to go back to previous formats.

Now I am trying to go back and change all of the prior numbering and get rid of the numbering, then start fresh again. It is a mess! Currently I am up to 4.6.3.1 and onward, and my previous section, which should have been 4.4.5.1 has changed to 4.6.3.1 to match the new format. How can I stop it changing my previous formatting?

Answer (score 3):

### If you use automatic paragraph numbering or bullets read Shauna Kelly's directions on numbering and bullets.

It all starts with the Define New **List Style** Dialog . You use that to create and name a list style, within that dialog, when you format numbering you go to the **Define MultiLevel List** Dialog. The key is to assign a separate existing paragraph style to each level of numbering. The styles can be built-in styles- or custom styles.

You need to be using Define New **List Style** or at least Define New **Multilevel List** Dialog. Start with [How to create numbered headings or outline numbering in Word 2007 and Word 2010](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html). *(Archival link in case site is down: http://web.archive.org/web/20130510174814/http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html)*

For large documents you must follow these directions or you will lose your hair!

(**Mac version**: https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/ *Archival link for Mac version: https://web.archive.org/web/20221102225202/https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/*)

This may seem a bit convoluted at first, but it really is not. Just follow the steps. Shauna Kelly's instructions use the built-in heading styles, but you can use any existing paragraph styles including your custom styles. There are, however advantages to using the built-in heading styles when you create a Table of Contents. Here are some more advantages: [Why Use Word's Built-In Heading Styles?](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm) by Shauna Kelly Note, you can modify these built-in styles to look exactly the way you want.

**Video on this:**

https://youtu.be/niD6VXPvAyU?t=487

The basic idea is that the numbering is set using the Define MultiLevel List dialog with each numbering level being attached to an existing paragraph style. Once you have this set up, you should not use the buttons for numbering in the Ribbon but rather apply the appropriate style for that level.

You can save a document with this as a template for future documents if you want so you will not need to do this every time.

**Styles in a multilevel list, when properly set up, can be a part of a [Quick] Style Set or transferred using a macro that uses the Organizer method.**

- [[Quick] Style Sets and Word Themes in Microsoft Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/quick-style-sets-and-word-themes-in-microsoft-word/444d4195-a28a-43bb-b035-facd84f7bd44)
- [[Quick] Style Sets](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#quick_style_set)
- [A Global Stylesheet for Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/word/stylesheet.htm#StartPage) - macro using organizer

You may also want to look [my prior answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word) posted here. It includes a screenshot.