# Is there a way to format a Q&A in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to have something like this:

```
Q: Is there a way to format a Q&A in Microsoft Word?

A: Sure all you need to do is ...
```

I know I can manually type "Q" and "A" at the beginning of each line, is there a way to format things so that it happens automatically similarly to what happens to a bullet point list.

Comment: You need to create your own Style:    http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/QandA2007.htm

Comment: @John I saw that and I was hoping there was a simpler way since to follow that seems like a lot of work for a one off project.

Comment: Styles is the only practical way for what you want. Simpler methods are for simpler structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Define New MultiLevel List dialog attaching the first two levels to a question and an answer style. You would not have numbering but would have the Q and A text in your list.

See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680).

Here is an example of the Define New MultiLevel List dialog. Note the attachment to styles and that the list is given a name.

[image: screenshot]

Here is a [temporary link to a document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzd0ptkybpwuune/Q%20and%20A%20styles%20in%20multilevel%20list.docx?dl=0) with these styles. A screenshot from that document appears below.

[image: Screenshot]