# Word Multilevel List numbering not restarting even finished with H1

Tags: microsoft-word, list, custom-multilevel-lists

After i create multilevel list in Word 2021 and at the end of list i add new Heading 1 or any other style or normal text paragraph that is not part of the first list, and then start new list excel still continues first list numbering rather than starting second list with 1.

I know i can manually reset numbering, but is there some way to separate numbered lists by some element of style that will tell excel "this list is finished, start new one"?

**Heading one**

1. Apple
2. Pear
3. Orange

**Heading Two**

4. Car
5. Boat
6. Airplane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Heading 1 needs to be attached to the first level in your MultiLevel List.

See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680).

[How to deal with advanced numbering in Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680)

The Heading 1 does not need to have any number attached to it, but it must be in the MultiLevel List definition.