# Word Indentation When Creating Numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, indentation

I have a simple question. If I insert (1) into a Word document, when I indent afterwards it automatically makes a small space (picture provided), after which an indent defaults to my desired distance. I have my default tabs set to .25", but no matter what I do, whenever I press tab, the tiny indent appears rather than my .25". I have the most recent version of Word.

This image shows exactly what the issue is:

[image: d]

Answer (score 0):

What you stumble on is the "automatic bullet list creation";
hit backspace immediately after the creation - once (enough?), or if that doesn't suit your needs;
try CTRL-Z once, twice or more, and see which level you're seeings as undoing the entire thing.

One might also look into the auto-thingie that does this, and disable it; I cannot help there though.

Comment: No progress, but thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, no Word to try in currently.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680): [How to deal with advanced numbering in Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680)

You want to be creating a list following procedures that attach numbering to predefined paragraphh styles using the Define New MultiLevel List Dialog.

And, yes, you want to turn off the AutoFormat as you Type option to create lists automatically. That is under File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options (button) > AutoFormat as you Type (tab in dialog box). See [Taming AutoFormat](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TameAutoFormat.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill.