# How to modify the indents in Table of Contents in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

I am not able to modify the indents in my "Table of Contents" in MS Word document. I have three levels of Headings in the "Table of Contents":

how can I  modify the indents between the number of the heading and the heading text , e.g. I have this heading "1  First Level Heading" (I need to increase the space between 1 and the heading text "First Level Heading").

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This can be a setting in your TOC styles or can be settings in the Define New MultiLevel List dialog. Please save a sample document with the problem in a cloud location and add a link to your question. For more about the MultiLevel List Dialog, which controls indents for numbering, see https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680.

Comment: @Charles Kenyon, Thank you very much. The link you provided is awesome. It is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Define New MultiLevel List Dialog controls the indents on Automatically Numbered paragraphs. Those indents are brought into the TOC to some extent.

Using this dialog is explored in my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680).

See also [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill and
[How to Create Numbered Headings or Outline Numbering](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) by Word MVP Shauna Kelly.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a table of contents that looks something like this

[image: Default table of contents]

Ensure your ruler is switched on.  Click one the level where you wish to modify the indent and drag the left indent (L on the ruler) to the right.  This will change the indent of all the items at that level.  In the picture below, I have changed the indent of level 2.  All the level 2s will follow the same indent.

[image: Level 2 indent changed]

Note that this will affect all future documents you write.  It does not go back to default even if you refresh the entire table.