# How to add tab between Level-1 and Level-2 in a multilevel list of MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

In a multi-level numbered list of MS Word, generally either Level-2 is added separately in a new line after the Level-1 or Level-1 and Level-2 are added together with a dot (.) separator

1. Level One

   1.(i) Level Two

But I want a tab in between Level-1 and Level-2 like this:
[image]

You can see that there is a tab space in between 5 and (i) but can't figured out how to do that. Can anyone help me in acheiving that type of formatting in a multilevel numbered list?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Steps

You can define a new multi-level list:

[image]

For the first level these are the settings:

[image]

For the second level:

- Include level number from *Level 1*
- Place the cursor in the text field *Enter formatting for number* between the number and the *i*
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to add a tab character

[image]

#### Result

[image]

Comment: One problem, You can see in your example 2 (i) starts after numbered list 2, ie, one paragraph is numbered as 2 and then the next paragraph is marked as 2. (i), but in attached image of the page, you can see that there is no paragraph marked as 5, It is started from the 5. (i) directly. I can't reproduce that format actually, I must have to mark a paragraph as 5 before marking another as 5. (i). What is the problem in my case?

Comment: Again: what have you tried? Have you looked up how to do this yourself? If so, please edit your question and include what you found, why it didn't work, and where you need help. Otherwise it sounds very much like "I have this problem, please solve it for me."

Comment: The answer above will work. I prefer going the extra step of attaching levels to separate paragraph styles. See: https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680. In the answer above, the sample uses the level 2 in paragraph 2. In your sample, you didn't use a level 2 until paragraph 5.

Comment: Hi @SaaruLindestøkke, I found one problem. Although the Ctrl+Tab works well while it is placed in multilevel text field, but as soon as, I close the MS Word file and reopen it, the tab converts into space automatically and the gap between Level 1 and Level 2 goes away. Do you have any idea why is it happening?