# How to format numbered format in mcq type in word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I have the following set of Multiple Choice Questions in word. The main question number is automatic , there is no problem here.

```
1. Sample Question 1
     a. Answer 1               b. Answer 2
     c. Answer 3               d. Answer 4
2. Sample Question 2
     a. Answer 1               b. Answer 2
     c. Answer 3               d. Answer 4
```

I have trouble setting the numbered list in the multiple choice answer.I want it to be automatic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the numbered list in the answer a , b, c , d to change automatically. Now I have to manually type in a, b ,c ,d

Comment: Trying VBA code?

Answer (score 0):

### For the numbering, you would use a MultiLevel list tied to styles.

I addressed how to do this in my answer on SuperUser in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680). This is far from intuitive. Please do follow the directions there.

I have an example doing this for multiple choice/guess tests as [Question and Answer Styles](https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#question). [image: screenshot] The document explains how it is done.

This uses three custom paragraph styles. You want to create the styles before setting up your MultiLevel list.

- The numbered **Question Style** is set at the top level of the Multilevel
  List. The style for the Question Style is set to have the Answer
  Style as the style for the following paragraph.
- The **Answer Style** with the letters has the Answer Style set for the
  following paragraph. It is the second level in the MultiLevel List.
- The **Answer Last Style** is based on the Answer Style. The difference is
  it has more space following and is set to use the Question Style as
  the following style.