# Word: Images/Symbols as a style in a paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I'm creating a word template for creating various documents.
I'd like an image to be part of a predefined style.
(It's just a small red rectangle, so if it's inserted as a character (e.g. a large minus sign) that's alight too.

I know how to do this in html/css and I'm pretty sure WordPerfect supports this at least from version 4, but I cannot find a way to do this in Word.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at my answer? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

### Rather than a Style, use Formatted AutoCorrect or AutoText/Building Blocks

Here is [one of Microsoft's pages on using AutoText / Building Blocks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-reusable-text-snippets-0bc40cab-f49c-4e06-bcb2-cd43c1674d1b).

Here is [my page on AutoCorrect and AutoText/Building Blocks](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm).

### This *could* be done using a style and a MultiLevel List but it is a kludge

You could define, say, level 9 of a MultiLevel List attached to styles to have your symbol instead of a number. See [my answer here about setting up such a list](https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680). Here is a [Microsoft Answers thread discussing this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/nested-styles-in-word/a3b1a34d-e84f-4b13-ac07-aae1bfde84f6).

You need to use the MultiLevel List dialog to get this degree of control. You use the Font button on that to control weight and color. Here is an screenshot showing the steps in doing this.

[image: dialog boxes]

Here is a [temporary link to the document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xd7xbukduz5k7mu/deleteme%20bar%20style%20heading%209.docx?dl=0) used in producing this screenshot.

Here is a screenshot from the document.

[image: screenshot]