# Creating List in MS word with numbers linked to heading number

Tags: microsoft-word, list, cross-reference

I am creating a document with several sections that each contain a heading number.

Many of the sections contain tables. The first column  in the table should contain a list of ID numbers.

The numbers should be composed of the heading-number followed by ".1" for row number 1 and ".2" for row number 2 and so forth. Preferably, when creating a new row, the first column should also automatically populate itself with the next in line list number.

How can I achieve this with automatic updating of the numbering? Say im creating a new section in between sections, then I would like the list numbers in the tables to update accordingly.

I am thinking if there is a way to combine multi-level lists with cross-references to heading numbers? Or an easier way?

Example:

5.3.2 Heading name

| ID | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5.3.2.1 | Random info 1 |
| 5.3.2.2 | Random info 2 |

Comment: I edited your post to change the word "header" to "heading." These are significantyldifferent features in Word and it is clear that you mean heading. https://addbalance.com/word/headersheadings.htm

Answer (score 0):

*See my answer in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680) for more details on setting up the numbering.*

### You want to be using a multilevel list that you set up following the prescriptions in [Shauna Kelly's seminal page on this](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

The key is that each of nine levels are set up attached to a unique character style. Then you use those styles to apply your numbering.

One shortcut for numbering like you are describing (called legal numbering) is to use the appropriate list style that comes with Word that tells you that the levels are attached to built-in headings.

[image: screenshot of multilevel list dialog]

When those styles are the built-in heading styles, [they have unique characteristics](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm). One of those is that the [Cross-Reference feature](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#crossreferences) in Word will link to them and can show just the paragraph number, or the text of the heading, or the page number it is on, or above/below. Even though it does not show up like a hyperlink, it acts as a link to that place in the document.

[image: screenshot of Cross-Reference dialog]

Disclosure: many of the links I provide are to locations on my website.