# How to find all lines with a certain style and add a character at the beginning of that line?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

In a Word document, I have lots of song titles and all are formatted with the same style. Aside from the song titles, no other content in the document is formatted with this certain style. The song titles are all in their own separate line/paragraph (line break before them and line break after them).
What I'd like to do is find every song title (scattered in the doc), and then add a character to the beginning of it.

**Example**

Current song title: `Let Me Call You Sweetheart` (in a certain style)

New song title: `[Let Me Call You Sweetheart` (in the same style)

Comment: Does any character follow after each song title (e.g. a colon ":")? Or are they maybe the only content in that line? If yes, then I'd have an idea.

Comment: Also, are only the song title in that specific style or could it be that other content is also formatted in that style?

Comment: Hi Loeli - I updated the main post to edit your questions. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer. If it works, please mark it answered. In case not, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 10-07-2023 (Reason: question has been edited):

1. Press CTRL + H to open the "Find and Replace" tool and click into the "Find what" field, but leave it completely empty
2. Click on "More>>"
   [image]
3. Click on "Format" > "Style"
   [image]
4. Select the style you are searching for and confirm with "OK"
   [image]
5. In the "Replace with" field, type in `[^&` but do NOT activate the wildcards. Finally, click on "Replace" or "Replace All"
   [image]

Word will now go through all paragraphs that have the style from step 4 applied to them and replace the paragraps with the same content (`^&`) and additionally put your desired character (`[`) in front of the paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have made it more clear - the text "Section One" is just a sample of the type of text that I need to substitute. Basically there's a ton of different song titles in a particular style, and I need each of them to have a [ in front of them. So somehow the style search needs to be combined with the wildcard search. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Sylvia I think the more complex problem here is, that a song title can probably consisit of multiple words. So, even if we find a wildcard option, Word would then place the "[" in front of every word is connected to this style. "Section One" for example would become "[Section [One". If the song titles are completely arbitrary, then you'll likely need a Macro for this instead of the Find and Replace function. Please give us more information about the song titles and the exact goal (please edit your question for that).

Comment: I edited the original question, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this! Works great. Turns out the style that I thought all the titles were in, were actually a couple different styles - one linked, one not, don't know how that happened - so I had to do in multiple steps, but it still works. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

### In your List Style add that character to the text. Numbering should be tied to Paragraph Styles beginning with the New List Style dialog.

This is laid out in detail in Shauna Kelly's page [How to Create Numbered Headings or Outline Numbering in Word](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html). Here are links to my responses here describing what is involved:

- [How to deal with advanced numbering](https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680)
- [Importing numbered paragraphs](https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033)

If you did this in setting up your current heading to reflect the One in Section One, it your special character would go into the numbering for that level before the word Section.