# Multilevel list with custom increment symbols

Tags: microsoft-word

Let's say I need to discuss 20 topics in my document and each topic should be its own chapter. The heading of every chapter should start with a custom character code like `AB` and then be followed by a standard readable chapter title. So, the first chapter could for example be `AB Some topic that needs to be explained`, the second chapter could be `DE Another topic that needs to be explained` and so on. Here, the custome codes are `AB` and `DE` and since I'd have 20 topcis, I'd also have 20 of these custom codes.

Every chapter could then have sub-chapters. Their headings should again start with the custom character code and then be followed by a number. So, the first sub-chapter could for example be `AB-1 This is a sub-chapter heading`, the second sub-chapter would then be `AB-2 Another sub-chapter heading` and so on.

All the character codes are **sequential** codes. This means, that if we have a code list of `[AB, DE, MN, XY, ...]` for example, then `MN` could never come before `DE`. And with that background, I'd like to somehow create a multilevel list, that basically always increments through my custom codes. If the document already contains a Heading 1 that says `AB Something`, then whenever the user creates a new Heading 1, it should automatically start with `DE` . So I want the standard behaviour of a multilevel list, but with my own "number" increments.

Instead of

```
1 Heading

2 Heading

3 Heading
```

I want it to increment like

```
AB Heading

DE Heading

MN Heading
```

I already tried everything I know but couldn’t find any solution to that. Is there any way to define the leading values? In Excel for example I can define a custom list that I can then use with the fill handle.

Comment: Excel has many features not available in Word. You can add an Excel part to a Word document to use those features. I'm afraid I do not understand the levels you want. See https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680

Comment: @CharlesKenyon thank you; in this case I need to work with only Word. So basically the main thing I need, is that if a user clicks on the Heading 1 style, it doesn't number the paragraph like `1 Some heading text`, but rather it "numbers" it with my custom character code, so like `AB Some heading`. I have multiple of these character codes and they are all sequential. So, once the heading `AB Some heading` exists, the next time Heading 1 is applied, it should go like `DE Some heading`. Do you maybe know an easy solution for that with SEQ fields?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I also updated the question to be more precise and included (hopefully) better examples. Would be awesome, if you know a trick for that.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way that you can do this with a multilevel list.
Take a look at the [SEQ field](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields).

```
{ SEQ Top \* ALPHABETIC \* CharFormat }{ SEQ Top \* ALPHABETIC \* CharFormat }
```

This will give you numbering AB CD EF.
The fields could be saved as [AutoText](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoComplete) entries.

This is essentially like text.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Charles. Unfortunately this doesn't allow for fully customized letter code combinations and I can't use it in combination (automatically) with the heading styles :/ I guess there is no simply solution for this problem