Multiple numbering in Word with different headings
Good evening,
I need to format documents with inconsistent numbering. For example (see below) 2,2A, 2A1. Then the numbering goes back to normal
1   Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
1.1 To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header.
1.1.1   Themes and styles.
2   Save time in Word.
2.A Reading is easier, too, in the new Reading view.
2.A.1.  Reading is easier, too, in the new Reading view.
3   Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video.
3.1 To make your document look professionally.
Thanks

Welcome to Superuser. Could you share with us what you have tried and the research that you have done? You can break and restart numbering, and you can also, when you start a new numbering scheme, start at the number of your choice.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Rather than expect Word to understand the change in format, it makes more sense and produces a neater document to either use consistent numbering conventions, or put breaks between each section, each with its own TOC.

@DrMoishe Pippik. It would certainly make more sense to have a neater document but it is a client's document and needs to stay "as is" but with automatic numbering.

See https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680

Select a number heading, right click and choose "Define new Multilevel list", then add two new levels. in the Section 2 example above you'd simply choose level 4 and 5.

1
1.1
1.1.1
1.A
1.A.1

