# Keep Word from continuing list when autoformatting

Tags: microsoft-word

For whatever reason, Word has decided that whenever I try to insert a list using autoformat (for example, typing <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) in a document I've been working on, I'm trying to continue a list from somewhere earlier in the document. This is unfortunate, as it's decided that the dash-bullet list (the example I gave earlier) is the sixth-level format, and the numbered list is the second level (confusingly, first level is *also* a visually indistinguishable numbered list, just apparently a different sort?).

How do I get word to stop doing this?

Comment: AutoFormat as you type is a very unreliable way to handle lists. See http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html, http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html. and https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033 for info on more robust ways to handle numbering.